# Distribute values over set of tuples in Python

Tags: python, combinations

I'm trying to create a rota for paired conversations, due to the lockdown.

I have a list of colleagues.

And I have created a list of days.

I want to assign the days sequentially to each pair, until all pairs have been assigned.

But I can't figure out how to track whether a pair has already been assigned and how to "run to the end of colleagues".

Here's what I have:

```
import itertools
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

colleagues = ["C",
              "S",
              "D",
              "I",
              "P"]

colleague_pairs = sorted(list(itertools.combinations(colleagues, 2)))
start_date = dt.datetime.today() + dt.timedelta(days=5)
dates = [start_date]
current_date = dates[-1]
while len(dates) < (len(colleagues) -1):
    new_date = current_date + dt.timedelta(days=1)
    if new_date.weekday() < 5:
        dates.append(new_date)
    current_date = new_date
working_days = [date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for date in dates ] 


[('C', 'D'), ('C', 'I'), ('C', 'P'), ('C', 'S'), 
 ('D', 'I'), ('D', 'P'), 
 ('I', 'P'), 
 ('S', 'D'), ('S', 'I'), ('S', 'P')]
['2020-05-04', '2020-05-05', '2020-05-06', '2020-05-07']
```

I want to end up with all dates applied to all unique pairs:

```
{('C', 'D'): '2020-05-04'}
{('C', 'I'): '2020-05-05'}
{('C', 'P'): '2020-05-06'}
{('C', 'S'): '2020-05-07'}

{('S', 'D'): '2020-05-05'}
{('S', 'I'): '2020-05-06'}
{('S', 'P'): '2020-05-07'}

{('D', 'I'): '2020-05-06'}
{('D', 'P'): '2020-05-07'}

{('I', 'P'): '2020-05-07'}
```

I tried to iterate over all days, but obviously that didn't work:

```
for pair in colleague_pairs:
    for day in working_days:
        print({pair:day})

{('C', 'D'): '2020-05-04'}
{('C', 'D'): '2020-05-05'}
{('C', 'D'): '2020-05-06'}
{('C', 'D'): '2020-05-07'}
{('C', 'I'): '2020-05-04'}
{('C', 'I'): '2020-05-05'}
{('C', 'I'): '2020-05-06'}
{('C', 'I'): '2020-05-07'}
{('C', 'P'): '2020-05-04'}
{('C', 'P'): '2020-05-05'}
{('C', 'P'): '2020-05-06'}
{('C', 'P'): '2020-05-07'}
{('C', 'S'): '2020-05-04'}
{('C', 'S'): '2020-05-05'}
{('C', 'S'): '2020-05-06'}
{('C', 'S'): '2020-05-07'}
{('D', 'I'): '2020-05-04'}
{('D', 'I'): '2020-05-05'}
{('D', 'I'): '2020-05-06'}
{('D', 'I'): '2020-05-07'}
{('D', 'P'): '2020-05-04'}
{('D', 'P'): '2020-05-05'}
{('D', 'P'): '2020-05-06'}
{('D', 'P'): '2020-05-07'}
{('I', 'P'): '2020-05-04'}
{('I', 'P'): '2020-05-05'}
{('I', 'P'): '2020-05-06'}
{('I', 'P'): '2020-05-07'}
{('S', 'D'): '2020-05-04'}
{('S', 'D'): '2020-05-05'}
{('S', 'D'): '2020-05-06'}
{('S', 'D'): '2020-05-07'}
{('S', 'I'): '2020-05-04'}
{('S', 'I'): '2020-05-05'}
{('S', 'I'): '2020-05-06'}
{('S', 'I'): '2020-05-07'}
{('S', 'P'): '2020-05-04'}
{('S', 'P'): '2020-05-05'}
{('S', 'P'): '2020-05-06'}
{('S', 'P'): '2020-05-07'}
```

I feel like there must be a word for the combinations I want but I can't figure it.

How can I adjust what I have to what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of getting your exact proposed output, this is my current suggestion:

```
cp = colleague_pairs[:]
#cpKeys == colleague_pairs is unique pairs. All start with a key, basically.
cpKeys = {i[0] for i in colleague_pairs}
#Assign those keys to a date. That date is the day you start using that key.
#startDay = {k:working_days.index(v) for k,v in zip(cpKeys,working_days)}#x is arbitrary. Doesn't mean anything, here, as a name.
startDay = {'C':0,'D':2,'S':1,'I':3}
print(startDay)
#Make a dict of colleague_pair: 
final = {i:'' for i in sorted(colleague_pairs)}

for i in [('C', 'D'),
        ('C', 'I'),
        ('C', 'P'),
        ('C', 'S'),
        ('S', 'D'),
        ('S', 'I'),
        ('S', 'P'),  
        ('D', 'I'),
        ('D', 'P'),
        ('I', 'P'),]:
    #for each cp
    #declare the key
    key = i[0]
    #Get the date to use by connecting the key
    #to the startDay index position for working_days
    dateToUse = working_days[ startDay[key] ]
    final[i] = dateToUse
    startDay[key] += 1
    if startDay[key] >= len(working_days):
        startDay[key] = 0
```

I did it this way to get the exact output you propossed, in the order you proposed. The crux of the idea is to use first character of tuple as a key, and track the days each one starts at. If colleague_pairs is unique pairs, then this should pan out if each startDay is a different day.

Comment: Oops! Sorry! I definitely went about that answering a different question!! Sorry! Will edit. You can use the same idea of making a dictionary of {first colleage:startDate} to do what I think you actually asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to group by first letter and assign days from starting you will need to create a new bi-dimensional array as follows:

```py
colleague_pairs = [
    [('C', 'D'), ('C', 'I'), ('C', 'P'), ('C', 'S')],
    [('S', 'D'), ('S', 'I'), ('S', 'P')],
    [('D', 'I'), ('D', 'P')],
    [('I', 'P')]
]
```

To achieve this format you can use dictionaries like so:

```py
colleague_pairs = [('C', 'D'), ('C', 'I'), ('C', 'P'), ('C', 'S'), ('S', 'D'), ('S', 'I'), ('S', 'P'), ('D', 'I'), ('D', 'P'), ('I', 'P')]
colleague_pairs_dict = {}
for cp in colleague_pairs:
    key = cp[0]
    if key not in colleague_pairs_dict.keys():
        colleague_pairs_dict[key] = []
        colleague_pairs_dict[key].append(i)
    else:
        colleague_pairs_dict[key].append(i)

two_dim_colleague_pairs = colleague_pairs_dict.values()
```

Then with this you can use next code to get the desired output.

```py
working_days = ['2020-05-04', '2020-05-05', '2020-05-06', '2020-05-07']
desired_output = []
days_index = 0

for i in range(len(colleague_pairs)):
    for j in range(len(colleague_pairs[i])):
        desired_output.append( { colleague_pairs[i][j] : working_days[days_index] } )
        days_index += 1
        if(days_index == len(working_days)):
            days_index = abs(len(working_days) - len(colleague_pairs[i])) + 1
    days_index = abs(len(working_days) - len(colleague_pairs[i])) + 1
```